# Laravel редирект при логине после перехода на https

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

После перехода на https после входа в админку перенаправляет на /admin.
Не https://site.com/admin, а именно /admin.
При том, что логин успешно осуществляется, при возвращении на предыдущую страницу в админку перекидывает. Использую дефолтную аутентификацию.

В AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Других проблем нет, внутри админки все работает корректно, во фронтенде руты также работают.

.htaccess (кодом криво добавляется)

[image: .htaccess]

Comment: а как вы с http на https редиректите? `\URL::forceScheme('https');` - только этим?

Comment: @n.osennij .htaccess тоже прописан

Comment: и что там написано? покажите

Comment: @n.osennij добавила в вопрос